# how to find previous & forward relation of data in single query

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have table :

```
ID      Person_ID        Person_Relative_ID
 1         10                   20
 2         20                   30
 3         13                   15
 4         30                   40 
 5         55                   56
 6         40                   50
```

Here we can see the person & `person_relative_id` chain is going like 10 - 20 - 30 - 40 - 50

Now if user search `Person_Relative_ID` of `person_id` = 20 then result would be like: [All its relation]

```
          Person_Relative_ID
                  10
                  30
                  40 
                  50
```

Or user want to search `Person_Relative_ID` for `person_id` = 40 . then result like

```
 Person_Relative_ID
            10
            20
            30 
            50
```

Or user want to search `Person_Relative_ID` for `person_id` = 50 . then result like

```
Person_Relative_ID
      10
      20
      30
      40
```

Any suggestion really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure this is the most performance effective solution, and I'd have liked to deal with a single recursive CTE instead of two, but this works at least.

Just replace the references to the temporary table I used to test this, with your real table. But what it does, is it uses two recursive CTE's to find all references above (CTEUp) and below (CTEDown) your ID, and then shows them in order, except for your searched ID.

**Note**: This is for SQL Server, not Oracle.

```
-- Creating dummy variables for testing
DECLARE @PERSONS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Person_ID INT, Person_Relative_ID INT)

INSERT INTO @PERSONS VALUES (10,20), (20,30), (13,15), (30,40), (55,56), (40,50)

-- Variable for searched ID, the actual script begins here
DECLARE @SEARCHED_ID INT
SET @SEARCHED_ID = 20

;WITH CTEUp AS 
            -- Fetching all relations above the ID
        (SELECT Person_ID
        FROM @PERSONS
        WHERE Person_ID = @SEARCHED_ID
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT Person_Relative_ID
        FROM @PERSONS P
        JOIN CTEUp C ON C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
            AND P.Person_Relative_ID > C.Person_ID)
    , CTEDown AS 
            -- Fetching all relations below the ID
        (SELECT Person_ID
        FROM @PERSONS
        WHERE Person_Relative_ID = @SEARCHED_ID
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT P.Person_ID
        FROM @PERSONS P
        JOIN CTEDown C ON C.Person_ID = P.Person_Relative_ID
            AND P.Person_ID < C.Person_ID)  
-- Showing results
SELECT Person_ID
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM CTEDown
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM CTEUp) SRC
WHERE Person_ID <> @SEARCHED_ID --... minus the ID, as per your example
ORDER BY Person_ID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just gave a try in Oracle, could be better but still it works

```
with tab(ID, Person_ID, Person_Relative_ID) as (
          SELECT 1, 10, 20 from dual union all
          SELECT 2, 20, 30 from dual union all
          SELECT 3, 13, 15 from dual union all
          SELECT 4, 30, 40 from dual union all
          SELECT 5, 55, 56 from dual union all
          SELECT 6, 40, 50 from dual),
---------
--End of data preparation
---------
filter_tab as (
          select 40 as id from dual), --> Put the search id here
final_tab(person_id) as (
          select person_id
            from tab
           start with person_relative_id = (select id from filter_tab)
         connect by prior person_id = person_relative_id
           union 
          select person_relative_id
            from tab
           start with person_id = (select id from filter_tab)
         connect by prior person_relative_id = person_id)
select * 
  from final_tab 
 where not exists (select 'x' 
                     from filter_tab 
                    where id = person_id )
 order by 1;
```

Output:

```
PERSON_ID
---------
10
20
30
50
```

I just traversed to both ends from the start point, did union of the result and excluded the search id.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [LEAD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function. 
Here is a sample:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [n], LAG([n]) OVER(ORDER BY [n] ), LEAD([n]) OVER (ORDER BY [n])
FROM [dbo].[Nums]
```

it generates results:

```
n   LAG LEAD
1   NULL    2
2   1   3
3   2   4
4   3   5
5   4   6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL2005 and above, [SQL Recursive CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) structured SQL query can be used for querying hierarchical data models like in your case

Below query uses also [multiple CTE queries](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to prevent usage of unnecessary temp tables or table variables

```
declare @id smallint = 50 

;with cte as (
    select Person_ID, Person_Relative_ID 
    from PersonRelative 
    where Person_ID = @id OR Person_Relative_ID = @id
    union all
    select P.Person_ID, P.Person_Relative_ID 
    from PersonRelative P
    inner join CTE on CTE.Person_ID = P.Person_Relative_ID
), cte2 as (
    select Person_ID from cte
    union
    select Person_Relative_ID from cte
), cte3 as (
    select Person_ID, Person_Relative_ID 
    from PersonRelative 
    where Person_ID = @id OR Person_Relative_ID = @id
    union all
    select P.Person_ID, P.Person_Relative_ID 
    from PersonRelative P
    inner join CTE3 on CTE3.Person_Relative_ID = P.Person_ID
), cte4 as (
    select Person_ID from cte3
    union
    select Person_Relative_ID from cte3
)
select * from cte4 where Person_ID <> @id
union
select * from cte2 where Person_ID <> @id
```